# SQLAlchemy get attribute name from table and column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way in SQLAlchemy by reflection or any other means to get the name that a column has in the corresponding model? For example i have the person table with a column group_id. In my Person class this attribute is refered to as 'group' is there a way to dynamically and generically getting this without importing or call the Person class?

Comment: That seems unlikely, since the `Person` class is where the mapping between the attribute name (`group`) and column name (`group_id`) is defined.  That information doesn't exist anywhere else.

Comment: @larsks I had that suspicion but was hoping for any magic possibility:) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use inspect method of sqlAlchemy, which would return mapper object when passed for sqlAlchemy model.

DB column is returned when mapper object is accessed with respective attribute name of model using mapper.c[attribute_name]; So db column name can be fetched via mapper.c[attribute_name].name;

For fetching attribute name we can traverse over attribute names of model which can be obtained using mapper.attrs.keys() and then compare db column name with respect to associated attribute name as done in below code snippet.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect   

    mapper = inspect(model_class)
    attr = mapper.attrs
    keys = attr.keys()
    db_column_name = 'db_column_name'
    attribute_name = next((attr_name for attr_name in keys if mapper.c[attr_name].name == db_column_name), None)

    print(attribute_name)
```

Comment: could you append your answer with some commentary so that we could better understand your code?

Comment: Some imports and definitions would be useful: what are `inspect` and `model_name`?

Comment: added import and details now.

Answer (score 0):

Given a SQLAlchemy Core column and a SQLAlchemy ORM mapped table, you can obtain the name of the mapped attribute in the table by using the [Mapper.get_property_by_column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper.get_property_by_column) method:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm


Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "student"

    id = sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group = sa.Column("group_id", sa.Integer)


# We have a column (group_id) and want to see what attribute (group) it's mapped to
mystery_column = Student.__table__.c.group_id

mapper = sa.inspect(Student)
mapped_property = mapper.get_property_by_column(mystery_column)
assert mapped_property.key == "group"
```

You can see this being used inside [sqlalchemy-mixins](https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins/blob/d1475a58d9f5b27dd7a794d7c3acb496aad6fd29/sqlalchemy_mixins/inspection.py#L15-L23)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it is most likely not possible...